EF Core creates migration which contains table, that isn't referenced anywhere in code
I had the "ChatUser" table in my SQLite database. I deleted all references to it in configuration files and DataContext (there are basically no matches if I'm doing "ChatUser" search in all files), however, even when I'm hard deleting my database file and all previous migrations manually, it still appears in newly created migration. What could be the issue? Where do I need to look to completely erase it for my future migrations?

It sounds like the next step is to narrow down what's producing this table.  If this overall data model, when deployed anew, results in creating this table... What happens if you start with only a subset of the overall data model?  Is this table still created?  What does this table contain and how is it related to the tables you do expect or the models producing them?  Can you provide specific details?

You haven't given much detail here but I suspect that this is most likely due to a many-to-many relationship between two entities - perhaps Chat and User.
If you have configured a many-to-many relationship between two entities, then some kind of linker table is required. If you haven't manually defined one, EF will do it for you.

Try below steps to solve your problem

Delete Model Snapshot.
Check if there’s a ModelSnapshot file in the Migrations folder (usually named something like ModelSnapshot.cs). Sometimes this file keeps a record of the current model state. So delete this file manually.

After deleting migrations and snapshots, rebuild your project. And re-add initial migration.

If you had any custom configurations, such as Fluent API configurations or .Entity mappings, ensure they’re also removed.


